# Array Object processing need a array with all Id exist in array object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this.

```
[
{
  "id": 13,
  "name": "VA"
},
{
  "id": 14,
  "name": "NA"
},
{
  "id": 15,
  "name": "PA"
}

]
```

I need a new array with all id values like this [13,14,15]. Using javascript.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. We expect to see some attempt at solving the issue yourself. A coded example of what you have tried is good, if you don't have that, tell us what your research so far has shown you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map`

```js
var a=[
{
  "id": 13,
  "name": "VA"
},
{
  "id": 14,
  "name": "NA"
},
{
  "id": 15,
  "name": "PA"
}

]
console.log(a.map(e=>e.id))
```